# one div tag has z-index:2 how to change sub div tag z-index:3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I a have problem, that is I am using `multilevelpushmenu` in my site,

I gave `z-index:2` to the `.protect` class,
I would like to give `z-index:4` for `.r-icon` class,

It does not seem to be working.

```
<div class="protect">
    <div id="mp-menu">
        <nav>
             <h2 class="r-icon"><i class="fa fa-reorder"><img src="/images/home/menu-selection.png" width="22" height="17" id="sas"></i></h2>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help to figure out this error,
I just want show `.r-icon` on top of all the `div`'s.

Comment: your <div class="protect"> is not having a closing tag?

Comment: What means "it's not working"? Ofcourse it's working. In the context of the HTML in your post, z-indexing a child to higher level is meaningless though.

Comment: plz. check once.. and help to solve this probelm

Comment: when everything else fails go to drastic actions: .r-icon { z-index: 4 !important; }, altough I don't know if it's possible that a child element has higher z-index than the parent.

Comment: yes- Teemu,
but i need show .r-menu into top all div for satisfy my requirement

Comment: Rumplin- i was tried it boss, it also not working.

Comment: Rumplin- can you share your mail id ? plz.

Comment: @VenkatCh If so, then you have to place the `.r-icon` to the correct place within stacking order. Where is that, it's not possible to say without seeing the whole element structure involved in this. Please read the articles Chirag64 has linked to, you will get the idea of `z-index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` is only applicable when two elements are on the same level in the DOM tree (i.e. they have the same parent element). In your case, it doesn't seem to work since the class `.protect` and `.r-icon` are not siblings.

You can find more details regarding this in [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), especially in the **Stacking Contexts** part in the article.

Also, here's a link to [MDN's page on Stacking Context in z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in multi-push plugin, there is an illusion which lets you see as if the **parent menu** in behind the **sub menu**. But in **HTML** point of view it is **hidden (display:none;)** using jQuery. So if you wish to see the icon or the image above all. You have to position it so that it should stay there all the time.

Place a div outside the **div** with **id "mp-menu"**

Try something like this:

```
<div class="protect">
  <div style="position:absolute;z-index:999;top:20px;left:20px;">Your Image here</div>
  <div id="mp-menu">
     <nav>
        <h2 class="r-icon"><i class="fa fa-reorder"><img src="/images/home/menu-selection.png" width="22" height="17" id="sas"></i></h2>
     </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```